# AIX: change executable of a running program

Tags: process, executable, aix

I have a master process which forks & execs child processes with defined executable files. 
Master and child processes are running infinite loops. Master restarts them if they stop.

Now I want to update the executable files of child processes. Something like:
1. copy new executable files
2. kill child processes (when they're idle)
3. master process restarts them with new executables

But simple cp "new_exec" "old_exec" returns error:
"Cannot open or remove a file containing a running program."

Question(s): 
Can I use "cp -f new_file old_file"?
Would that affect old running processes (Is everything loaded into memory on process start)?

I am on AIX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use "cp -f new_file old_file"?
>   Would that affect old running processes (Is everything loaded into memory on process start)?

'No' and 'yes'. But, if you had asked how to solve this, I would say either:

```
rm /oldpath/exec
cp /newpath/exec /oldpath/exec
```

or rather:

```
cp /newpath/exec /oldpath/exec_replace
mv /oldpath/exec_replace /oldpath/exec
```

Comment: The second method is preferred because the me will be atomic.

Comment: Ok, thanks. According to man cp: `cp -f` deletes old file and then copies new. So mv is better because its atomic. I just need to run it with `mv -f` to disable prompt before overwrite.